# Factory Pattern - String or Enums?

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern

I have been wondering from the designs standpoint, whether it is better to pass an enum as parameter to the factory class as opposed to a String?

Let's take the code below as an example:

```
class SomeFactory{

   public SomeObject getObject(String objectType){

      switch(objectType){

         case "TYPEA":
            return new SomeObjectA();

         case "TYPEB":
            return new SomeObjectB();

         default:
            {handle the situation of missing / or misspelled request here}

      }
   }
}
```

Now, I believe that the implementation above is error prone to typos and inside an IDE you would have to navigate to the factory class source and see what is acceptable as an input...

Instead of doing this I was thinking that creating a public inner enum, say called SOMEOBJECTS, and storing all possible variants there, would be a much safer choice.

The implementation would look something like this:

```
class SomeFactory{

   // public inner enum that can be accessed through the factory.
   // preferably the name of the enum should be a all caps version of
   // the interface or super class that the subtypes (TYPEA, TYPEB..)
   // are implementing / extending.
   public enum SOMEOBJECTS{
      TYPEA,
      TYPEB,
      TYPE...
   }

   public SomeObject getObject(SOMEOBJECTS objectType){

      switch(objectType){

         case TYPEA:
            return new SomeObjectA();

         case TYPEB:
            return new SomeObjectB();

         default:
            // Putting a default as a good practice, even though the input now has been
            // restricted to whatever is inside the enum class.

      }
   }
}
```

The only caveat I can think of to this, is that in order to access the enum you have to type `SomeFactory.SOMEOBJECTS.TYPE..;`.

Perhaps I'm obsessing over this, but I believe that this extra line of code needed in a enum class whenever updating the factory class can go a long way.

I frequently see in books and online articles the first examples of the factory pattern in Java using a String as parameter.

Would you agree with this approach or are there better ways that I am not aware of when it comes to implementing the factory pattern?

Comment: This is a question likely to lead to opinions. Functional programmers will tell you that enums are better because you don't need a default. JavaScript programmers will use a string all day long and twice on Sunday. It all depends on what gives you and your team confidence.

Comment: Oh, JavaScript programmers.

Comment: @DCTID I have tagged this under Java specifically, so I'm not sure how cross-language opinions would arise. Although I understand what you mean.

Comment: @jEdringer I don't think it matters that you added [meta-tag:Java]. This is a question for all programmers, is limiting the options of a switch or case important? Long and short, it's all opinion. I do have one but not sure this is the correct place.

Comment: This is also going to vary depending on the kind of factory. Is it intended to be extensible at runtime, such as JDBC and other SPI plugin systems? If so, you need an arbitrary string.

Comment: @DCTID but I am interested in opinions as I mentioned at the end of the post. Perhaps Reddit would be a better place for debatable subjects, you're right.

Comment: The best place for the question is [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). I don't think this is too much opinion based considering the question as it is, i.e. enum vs string. It's objectively always enum.

Comment: I'm still not comfortable with the whole idea of using strings in case blocks :(

Answer (score 2):

To use an enum there is obviously the best way as it gives you the safety that every call has a valid argument. Of course this comes with the overhead of maintenance but you should rather prefer that than having the program crushing because some invalid string.

---

Another thing I'd like to mention is that it's strange to have a factory method to create instances of different types. A factory class should be dedicated to one type. Then you wouldn't have to pass a type as argument. You could make use of multiple `getObject` methods as well that return different types depending on the arguments.

---

*FYI:* You can pass the *type* by type.

```java
public static <T> T getObject(Class<T> type)
        throws InvocationTargetException, IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, NoSuchMethodException {
    return type.getConstructor().newInstance();
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Object o = getObject(Object.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // I don't care.
    }
}
```

This is obviously bad (or rather *can* be when used wrong) but maybe this will give you another perspective on the topic. Note that the generic can be used like `<T extends SomeObject>`, you can compare types .. Many things are possible.

Comment: By different types I mean different implementations of an interface (or a subclass), probably should have expressed that better. The type implementation seems like a good idea, since you're checking if the type is a "subclass of" or "implements a"... Interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

I think that the way you are implementing it using the enum would be a better way to use the String.

It makes sense to have the enum be an inner type because the values within the enum relate directly to SomeFactory.

If at some point you wanted to get an enum from a String value passed into your application you could always do this:

```
SomeObjects.valueOf(string.toUpperCase());
```

(Where string is the string value passed into your application)